# object not found in mediation model

Tags: r, lm, stat

I have to plan a simple mediation model - https://cran.r-project.org/package=mediation

```
library(mediation)

mediation_model = lm(as.numeric(Age) ~ as.numeric(condition), data = GRA)
tab_model(mediation_model)

model = lm(as.numeric(note) ~ as.numeric(condition) + as.numeric(Age), data = GRA)
tab_model(model)

result <- mediate(mediation_model,model,sims = 120,mediator="as.numeric(Age)",treat="as.numeric(condition)",boot = TRUE)
```

And it generates this error:

> Running nonparametric bootstrap
>
> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Age' not found

I taped 'manes(GRA)' and I found 'Age'. The lm works well, I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: Not familiar with "mediation" package, but try to convert to numeric before running models, before lm: `GRA$Age <- as.numeric(GRA$Age)` and same for "condition", then run lms, then mediate, with mediator as simply "Age".

Comment: It's tha, thanks. Now it works well.

Comment: I made all my code with this non numeric variable without problem. It's why I not expected that

Comment: `lm` is able to operate because you explicitly told it to convert variables to `numeric`-class. Anything downstream that wants to work on the model expects that the data then has these same variables already as `numeric`, there is no attempt to _recreate_ the steps taken on the data. (To be clear ... in ML and some forecasting work in R, there is "feature engineering" that does something akin to recording the data-munging steps, and when the model is used on new data, the steps are recreated/rerun on the new data. That's a great notion, but it is not part of `lm` and `lm`-derived summaries.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll formalize the comments.

Any steps you perform on the data within the formula are not carried forward for any post-model analysis. This means that when you run `mediate`, the versions of `note`, `condition`, and `Age` are their original class within your `GRA` data; the coefficients in `model` suggest that they should be numeric, but number-like operations are not working.

As a counter-point, in many ML and forecasting (in R) pipelines, the "feature engineering" or pre-conditioning steps are recorded in a sense, so that when you apply that ML/forecasting model to new data, the steps are repeated on the new data. This is a novel and great way to handle modeling, but unfortunately `lm` and friends are not based on that architecture.

(Disclaimer: I don't know `mediate` and don't have it installed, I'm not speaking to the correctness of your regression or its use.)

Convert the columns into a frame (either overwriting `GRA` or saving to a new frame, `GRA2` below), and then don't worry about `as.numeric(.)` in either of your calls to `lm(.)` or `mediate(.)` (or any other model-using function):

```r
GRA2 <- GRA |>
  transform(
    note = as.numeric(note),
    condition = as.numeric(condition),
    Age = as.numeric(Age)
  )
mediation_model = lm(Age ~ condition, data = GRA2)
model = lm(note ~ condition + Age, data = GRA2)
result <- mediate(mediation_model, model, sims = 120,
                  mediator="Age", treat="condition", boot = TRUE)
```

Also, there are other ways to convert those three columns, this is just one. My point is not that you must use `transform`, feel free to use whatever R code you want to pre-convert the three columns into a frame, and then use that frame in calls to `lm` and `mediate`.